# Databinding LINQ query results (with join tables) to DataGrid

Tags: wpf, linq, data-binding, datagrid, join

In my WPF 4 desktop-based application, I have an LINQ query that makes a join with two tables.

Here is code for function that returns results of LINQ query:

```
public IList GetTableData()
{
    IList dataList = (from dWorker in App.glidusContext.tbl_workers
        join d2 in App.glidusContext.tbl_workers_has_tbl_events
        on dWorker.workerID equals d2.workerID
        where dWorker.workerTZ == strSplit
        select new { dWorker, d2 }).ToList();
    return data list;
}
```

Now, all what I rest to do is data bind results of this LINQ query to `DataGrid`:

```
private IList currentData; //class property

public void AssignTableContentToDataContext() {
    currentData = GetTableData();
    this.ContentDataGrid.DataContext = currentData;
}
```

And here is an XAML-code of DataGrid:

```xml
<DataGrid x:Name="ContentDataGrid"
          Style="{StaticResource Body_Content_DataGrid}"
          CellStyle="{StaticResource Body_Content_DataGrid_Centering}"
          ItemsSource="{Binding}"
          KeyboardNavigation.TabIndex="8"
          SelectionChanged="ContentDataGrid_SelectionChanged" DataContext="{Binding}">
    <!--  PreviewKeyDown="DBRecord_Delete_PreviewKeyDown" -->
    <!--  CellEditEnding="ContentDataGrid_CellEditEnding" -->
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="{x:Static res:Resources.WinSafetyByEmployee_DataGrid_ColHead_WorkerID}"
                            Width="130"
                            IsReadOnly="True"
                            Binding="{Binding Path=workerID}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="{x:Static res:Resources.WinSafetyByEmployee_DataGrid_ColHead_workerTZ}"
                            Width="130"
                            Binding="{Binding Path=workerTZ}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="{x:Static res:Resources.WinSafetyByEmployee_DataGrid_ColHead_WorkerFirstName}"
                            Width="130"
                            Binding="{Binding Path=workerFirstName}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="{x:Static res:Resources.WinSafetyByEmployee_DataGrid_ColHead_WorkerLastName}"
                            Width="130"
                            Binding="{Binding Path=workerLastName}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="{x:Static res:Resources.WinSafetyByEmployee_DataGrid_ColHead_EventID}"
                            Width="130"
                            Binding="{Binding Path=eventID}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="{x:Static res:Resources.WinSafetyByEmployee_DataGrid_ColHead_EventName}"
                            Width="*"
                            Binding="{Binding Path=eventName}" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

After debug I got the following results:

1. My query returns rows with results
2. My `DataGrid` shows lines, according to number of lines in the query result, but they are blank!

How can I data bind this data and show them in `DataGrid`?

P.S. In case of more simple query such as `select * from _table_` everything works fine and `DataGrid` shows data, but when I use more complex queries with more than one table (make join) I can't databind it correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LINQ-join works different from SQL-join. It doesn't merge different sources in one plain source.
So change each binding in the `DataGrid` like in this example:

```
{Binding Path=workerID}
```

for

```
{Binding Path=dWorker.workerID}
```

Or `d2.workerID`, I don't know the properties of these classes, but the mistake is in the bindings.

And don't forget to set `IsReadOnly="True"` in the `DataGrid`, because otherwise it will raise an exception if to start editing.

Answer (score 2):

You dont have to use entity alias in your binding clause. Just put the column name on the Binding clause

```
<DataGridTextColumn Width="200" Header="CPF" IsReadOnly="True" Binding="{Binding Path=NumeroDoc}">
```

Remove .ToList() from your code, returning a IEnumerable object

```
public static IEnumerable getQueryTable()
    {
        var dataList = (from c in App.DbContext.Cliente
                 join d in App.DbContext.DadosDocumento
                 on c.IDCliente equals d.IDCliente
                 select new { c.IDCliente, c.Nome, c.DataCadastro, d.NumeroDoc });
        return dataList;
    }
```

And fill the datagrid using ItemsSource property:

```
dgDados.ItemsSource = DBHelper.getQueryTable();
```

It works fine for me.